# Hibernate exception inserting into database at startup

Tags: java, sql, spring

I am currently learning Spring from the book "Spring in Action". I want to insert data into my H2 database when starting the server. Since it doesn't work like in the book, I follow [this](https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-boot-loading-initial-data/) guide. The tables are created, but no data in it.

This is the error I receive:

```
2022-01-18 21:52:01.361  WARN 44885 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", "WRAP")" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", "WRAP")" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at com.example.tacocloud.TacoCloudApplication.main(TacoCloudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "FLTO" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", "WRAP") [42122-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.getColumnException(ExpressionColumn.java:163) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:145) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.prepare(Insert.java:327) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:744) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

My import.sql looks like the following:

```
delete from Taco_Order_Tacos;
delete from Taco_Ingredients;
delete from Taco;
delete from Taco_Order;

delete from Ingredient;
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('FLTO', 'Flour Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('COTO', 'Corn Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('GRBF', 'Ground Beef', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('CARN', 'Carnitas', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('TMTO', 'Diced Tomatoes', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('LETC', 'Lettuce', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('CHED', 'Cheddar', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('JACK', 'Monterrey Jack', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('SLSA', 'Salsa', 'SAUCE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('SRCR', 'Sour Cream', 'SAUCE');
```

The Ingredient class has:

```
private final String id;
private final String name;
private final Type type; // an enum: WRAP, SAUCE, ...
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The problem is double quotes in the insert. It should be 'FLTO' not "FLTO".  import.sql has NO double quotes, right? Any ideas where the double quotes come from?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to your application.properties file and check because hibernate may not be detecting your queries as MySQL queries(native queries).

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Also, if you see values in the query in the first line of your error stack trace, they are inside double-quotes. Do something so that values come in single quotes because using double quotes for values is a bad practice. Backticks are only used for table and column names so use backticks around table and column names and use double quotes for surrounding queries.

Answer (score 0):

H2 db uses the same syntax as Mysql under the covers. As already said, H2/Mysql does not accept double quotes. Looking at your import.sql file it seems to be all right. However, your console shows double quotes for the column values.

Try to check if your script.sql is not running before hibernate creates the tables. This would cause an error.

You can try putting this in your configuration class:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

This will make Hibernate create the tables before your script values ​​are entered.